# Evaluate $\int_{-2}^2\int_{y^2-3}^{5-y^2}dydx$

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

> $$\int_{-2}^2\int_{y^2-3}^{5-y^2}dydx$$

My problem is that I don't see the area that I should calculete, it looks weird

**Attempt:**

$$\int_{-2}^2 \bigg( (5-y^2)-(y^2-3)\bigg) \color{red}{dx}$$

$$\int_{-2}^2 \bigg( 8-2y^2 \bigg) \color{red}{dx}$$

Comment: In the words as adapted from sixth sense.."I see two integrals." . Can you give some more context.

Comment: the integral as it stands is not well-defined (integral bounds and and integrator the same?) could you give the complete exercise?

Comment: they asked me to draw the graphs and to calculte the integrals, this is all the details

Comment: It is something weird with the integral. The boundaries in the inner integral depend on the inner integration variable (!!!) The inner integral does not depend on $x$, i.e. a constant (???) Maybe the integral should read $dxdy$ instead? Especially if we take into account the two lines (green and yellow) corresponding $y=-2$ and $y=2$, so $-2$ and $2$ are boundaries for $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt has an error. The last integral is in $dy$ not in $dx$. You can find that the value of the correct integral is $\dfrac{64}{3}$ . If you trace the complete graphs of the two parabolas ( also the part with $y<0$) , this is the area of the finite sector of plane delimited by the two graphs.

The integral become: 
$$\int_{-2}^{2}dy\int_{y^2-3}^{5-y^2}dx=\int_{-2}^{2}(8-2y^2)dy=\left( 8y-\dfrac{2}{3}y^3\right)_{-2}^2=\dfrac{64}{3}
$$
Note that this correspond to the calculus of the area of a sector of parabola by means of the [Archimedes formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicSegment.html) for the two segments of parabolas.

Comment: No, it's not correct. (Integral of $y$ with respect to $x$ equals a constant?)

Comment: Hint. The integral $\int_{-2}^{2}$ is an integral in $dy$: see the add to my answer.

Comment: @HansLundmark: there was an error in the OP differential. I've specified the exact solution.

Comment: What I meant was that the statement "your attempt is correct" is not correct.

Comment: Ies, I agree. I've not see the error in my first inspection. So now I edit.

Comment: Much better now. :-)