# Evaluate$\int_{-2}^2\int_{y^2-3}^{5-y^2}dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

I evaluated this integarl:

> $$\int_{-2}^2\int_{y^2-3}^{5-y^2}dxdy=\boxed{\frac{64}{3}}$$

Now I need to evaluate it with changing the limits,

**My attempt:**

$$=\int_{-3}^1 \bigg[\int_0^{\sqrt{x+3}}dy\bigg]dx+\int_{1}^5 \bigg[\int_0^{\sqrt{5-x}}dy\bigg]dx$$

$$\int_{-3}^1 \sqrt{x+3}dx+\int_{1}^5 \sqrt{5-x}dx=\boxed{\color{red}{\frac{32}{3}}}$$

> Where am I wrong?

Comment: You don't solve an integral, you compute or evaluate it.

Comment: English is not my first language

Comment: Why do you change limits?

Comment: this is the exercise

Comment: Possible duplicate of the exact same question you posted earlier: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1360815/evaluate-int-22-int-y2-35-y2dydx

Comment: it is not duplicate the link that you gave is before changing the limits

Comment: Have you not a solution in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1360815/evaluate-int-22-int-y2-35-y2dydx..... What have you tried here?

Comment: Why do you stop plotting parabolas on the $x$-axis? The plots should continue to negative values of $y$ too, at least until the lower integration boundary $y=-2$. It is necessary to have the correct picture, especially if you want to train with iterated integrals due to Fubini theorem.

Comment: @EmilioNovati now it is with changing the limits

Comment: OK. The problem is that you have to use also the negative values for $y$. As un the answer of @darya.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

$$\int_{-3}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{x+3}}^{\sqrt{x+3}}dydx + \int_{1}^{5} \int_{-\sqrt{5-x}}^{\sqrt{5-x}}dydx=\\2 (\int_{-3}^{1}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{x+3}}dydx + \int_{1}^{5} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{5-x}}dydx)$$

Comment: what did you use for plotting? looks nice!